# Why doesn't yshift seem to work in tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

In the tikz-cd documentation, the following code snipped is given:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[yshift=0.7ex]{r} \arrow[yshift=-0.7ex]{r}
& B \arrow[xshift=0.7ex]{d} \arrow[xshift=-0.7ex]{d} \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
```

and the following is shown as example output:

[image]

However, when I copy and paste this code into my document and attempt to run it, the result looks like this instead:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: No problems here. Perhaps you are using outdated package(s)? This is the version of `tikz-cd` in my system:  `tikz-cd.sty    2012/12/30 v0.3c Commutative diagrams with tikz`.

Comment: Ah -- I thought that Repository > Synchronize in MikTeX package manager would do something about outdated packages, but this doesn't seem to be the case.  I'm running the update wizard now and hopefully my problems go away.

Comment: Let us know the result; if once the updating process is finished, the problem disappear, most probably this question will be closed as "Too localized". If the problem persist, we'll try to help you.

Comment: Okay, after updating my packages and cleaning up the resulting mess the yshift seems to be working correctly.  Thanks for the help!